# gstreamer 1.0 android - video de-compositing with videobox to multiple surfaces

Tags: android, gstreamer

I am trying to decompose a video stream that was encoded from multiple input sources through a compositor element, which is working fine.

I am trying to take that stream and split it with tee after decoding and passing each src pad of the tee to a videobox element to crop the segment corresponding to the composite stream to unique surface instances in android.
Actually, I think the issue is more with how I'm (mis)using videobox.

I can use a single videobox element fine and it crops out the correct composited segment, but when I use multiple videobox elements, there seems to be no flow to the downstream elements.

I'm getting similar symptoms on my Windows and Mac machines, but the target platform is Android.

As an example, this Mac pipeline works:

gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.0.25:7768/tiles ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! vtdec  ! tee name=t  ! queue ! videoconvert ! videobox left=0 right=960 top=0 bottom=540 ! glimagesink render-rectangle='<990,570,960,540>'

This Mac pipeline runs, but nothing is displayed and no errors:

gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.0.25:7768/tiles ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! vtdec  ! tee name=t  ! queue ! videoconvert ! videobox left=0 right=960 top=0 bottom=540 ! glimagesink render-rectangle='<990,570,960,540>'   t.  ! queue ! videoconvert ! videobox left=960 right=1920 top=0 bottom=540 !  glimagesink render-rectangle='<20,20,960,540>'

Appreciate any feedback
- Doug

Answer (score 0):

I had interpreted the use of left/right/top/bottom incorrectly.  After reading info on videocrop, I discovered those parameters indicate how much to crop off of each corresponding edge.

This works: (right=0 on second occurrance on videobox)

gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.0.25:7768/tiles ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! vtdec ! tee name=t ! queue ! videoconvert ! videobox left=0 right=960 top=0 bottom=540 ! glimagesink render-rectangle='<990,570,960,540>' t. ! queue ! videoconvert ! videobox left=960 right=0 top=0 bottom=540 ! glimagesink render-rectangle='<20,20,960,540>'

That's what I get for working late on Friday : )